# Emacs Calc IEEE 754 binary representation

Tags: calc, binary

Does Emacs Calc have IEEE 754 representation for binary numbers?
I found only "The Calculator’s arithmetic is not intended to be IEEE-conformant in any way", but I try maybe there is a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve already read the documentation that says that it is not using IEEE 754 floating–point numbers, so why do you ask? Some relevant parts of [chapter 5.3 Floats](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Floats.html) from The GNU Emacs Calculator reference:

> A floating-point number or “float” is a number stored in scientific
> notation.  The number of significant digits in the fractional part is
> governed by the current floating precision (*note Precision::).  The
> range of acceptable values is from ‘10^-3999999’ (inclusive) to
> ‘10^4000000’ (exclusive), plus the corresponding negative values and
> zero.
>
> […]
>
> Floating-point numbers are stored in decimal, not binary.  The
> result of each operation is rounded to the nearest value representable
> in the number of significant digits specified by the current
> precision…  The Calculator’s arithmetic is not
> intended to be IEEE-conformant in any way.

Note especially that the range of representable values goes far beyond what IEEE 754 provides. An IEEE 754 quad decimal float only accepts values with exponents in the range from −6143 to +6144.